# How to calculate visual angle when presenting a 2D image Google VR?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, daydream

I am new to developing in Unity, but would like to show a static image to my participants in an experiment.

I have difficulty understanding what the visual angle will be of said image and how I can control it.

[image: visual angle]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visual angle would probably be the field of view, of the camera. If you are just using the default unity camera, you can set the field of view on the script.

If you are just placing two cameras, (one for each side of the screen / one for each eye), you would want them to be the same. You can change the field of view via script with `Camera.fieldOfView`. By changing it via script, you could change them at the same time, by the same amount.